# How to use .Net Framework 3.5 or 4.5 depending on which ever is available

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, .net-framework-version

My app uses **.net 3.5**, and compiles successfully under **4.5** without any modifications, so apparently the libraries my app uses exists both in 3.5 & 4.5. But **windows 8** explicitly requires 3.5 even though 4.5 is available.

How can I (programatically) make my app use 3.5 when running on windows7 and 4.5 when running on windows8?

PS: Ideally I want to avoid using an app.config file

Comment: "PS: Ideally I want to avoid using an app.config file" Why is that? Because that does exactly what you seem to want (using `<supportedRuntime>`)

Comment: @hvd afaik it won't work, because SupportedRuntime has list of version that can run with, and with 3.5 there is no 4.0 in it ;)

Comment: @cichy A VS .NET 3.5 project will not have a `<supportedRuntime>` element for .NET 4 by default, nor should it, but if you've tested to see that it works, you can add it yourself.

Comment: As they say, you learn something everyday ;) will test that later on clean Virtual Machine ;)

Comment: If Windows 8 *requires* 3.5, and your app uses 3.5 anyway, why would you want to use 4.5 at all?

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't explicitly require 3.5, it isn't even installed by default.  But just a checkbox away in Programs + Features, Windows Setup.  Targeting 3.5 is fine but you'll either need that checkbox turned on or use a .config file to tell .NET that running on CLR version 4 is fine.

Comment: @hvd Efforts were made to keep the app as a single assembly without an installer

Comment: @ChristianSpecht v3.5 is not enabled by default on windows 8, it will first have to be downloaded and installed

Comment: Note that according to the answers in [this question](http://superuser.com/q/491000/85165) the 3.5 framework is included in windows 8, but not installed automatically. It will be if your program needs it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I could think to do, is to compile for both frameworks.  And include both in your installer package, using it to install the correct one based on what you find on the system.

Comment: That will be one way of doing it which doesn't require an _app.config_ file. But in the absence of a compile-time/manifest based solution I'll go with the <supportedRuntime version> element for now. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Note that according to the answers in [this question](http://superuser.com/q/491000/85165) the 3.5 framework is included in windows 8, but not installed automatically. It will be if your program needs it.

Answer (score 5):

For App developers (and IT Administrators):
IT administrators can configure .NET 3.5 apps to run on either .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.5 (depending on what's already installed). In order to run a managed app on either 3.5 or 4.5, just add a section in the application configuration file. This will ensure that if .NET 3.5 is installed, the app will run on .NET 3.5; otherwise the app will run on .NET 4.5. An example of the additional section in the configuration file is provided below:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a solution which didn't have a dependency on an additional file. But the simplest way I could get my **.net 3.5** app to work on **windows 8** was creating an *app.config* file(which I wanted to avoid) and adding the "`<supportedRuntime>`" element.

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what will be name of the config file.I have one dll called mydll.dll

Answer (score 0):

Win8 will detect the need for 3.5 and seamlessly prompt the user to install it.  Not really worth jumping through hoops to further streamline

Comment: Hmm, I've tested this once and so far have a 100% failure rate.  The installer goes first.

Comment: In my scenario it is important I spare the user the hassle of downloading and installing the .NET framework.